# Concatenate on csv files and adding new row

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning

When I try to concatenate my csv files, last two column of each csv files are placed in the same column. How can solve this issue?

Second question, I would like to add new row as output to each file.

Here is my codes and example ;

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os

path = r'/Users/isozyesil/PycharmProjects/P300/Data/TestP300'  # use your path

allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_, index_col=None, header=0)
    list_.append(df)



frame = pd.concat(list_)
print(list_)
```

Here is example of my problem ;

```
Last 6 row of A.csv : 

4  -1.6144  -0.7137  1.2791  -0.8205
5  -2.4333  -0.9433  0.9616  -2.3392
6  -2.3548   0.0945  0.9933  -3.1174
7  -3.0944  -0.8559  0.6441  -2.8976
8  -0.4791  -0.8795  0.7027  -2.7338 
9  -3.6540  -6.2700  0.2650  -4.0410

Last First 4 row of B.csv :  
0  -3.1024  -1.8710  0.1311  -5.7071
1  -0.1855  -0.8241 -0.2756  -6.6962
2  -3.2941  -2.0557  0.2471  -4.4969
3  -1.5004  -0.2482  0.9565  -0.6866


Here is what happens when I run my code : 

4  -1.6144  -0.7137  1.2791  -0.8205
5  -2.4333  -0.9433  0.9616  -2.3392
6  -2.3548   0.0945  0.9933  -3.1174
7  -3.0944  -0.8559  0.6441  -2.8976
8  -0.4791  -0.8795  0.7027  -2.7338,  -3.6540  -6.2700  0.2650 -4.0410,
0  -3.1024  -1.8710  0.1311  -5.7071
1  -0.1855  -0.8241 -0.2756  -6.6962
2  -3.2941  -2.0557  0.2471  -4.4969
3  -1.5004  -0.2482  0.9565  -0.6866

Here is what I dream to do

4  -1.6144  -0.7137  1.2791  -0.8205  A
5  -2.4333  -0.9433  0.9616  -2.3392  A
6  -2.3548   0.0945  0.9933  -3.1174  A
7  -3.0944  -0.8559  0.6441  -2.8976  A
8  -0.4791  -0.8795  0.7027  -2.7338  A
9  -3.6540  -6.2700  0.2650  -4.0410  A
0  -3.1024  -1.8710  0.1311  -5.7071  B
1  -0.1855  -0.8241 -0.2756  -6.6962  B
2  -3.2941  -2.0557  0.2471  -4.4969  B
3  -1.5004  -0.2482  0.9565  -0.6866  B
```

Thanks in advance to every python fighter.

Comment: what is the output of `print(frame)`?

Comment: -0.0084  -0.0266  -0.1331  -0.2933  -0.3348  -0.8568  -0.8621  -0.9148  \
0       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  -2.4155   
1       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  -0.2417   
2       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  -2.3314   
3       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  -2.3340   
4       NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  -1.6144   
 

[72 rows x 32 columns]

Comment: Consider there are bunch of Nan @MaxU

Comment: Why are there commas after the 8th and 9th row in A.csv?  I'm asking because in python, the comma can be used at the end of print to avoid a linefeed at the end of the line.  Of course, you are not calling print , but the comma at the end of the line may mean something to your library.

Comment: Actually, there is no comma, I copied the results from output as a shortway. I just checked the each file, there are only comma between numbers not at the end of lines. I am editing it right away.

Comment: I found the problem, eventhough there is no header, first column is considered as header. I have to mention there is no header on those files. :)   Now, first question is evolved.

Comment: First question is completely solved, header=None solves the problem. You are a life saver @MaxU

Comment: Now, I have to find a way to add new row without causing any problem on the datas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob(r'D:\temp\.data\43076965\*.csv')

x = pd.concat(
    [pd.read_csv(f, header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
       .assign(f=os.path.basename(os.path.splitext(f)[0]))
     for f in files],
    ignore_index=True
)

x.to_csv(r'd:/temp/out.csv', header=None, index=False, sep='\t')
```

Result (`d:/temp/out.csv`):

```
4   -1.6144 -0.7137 1.2791  -0.8205 A
5   -2.4333 -0.9433 0.9616  -2.3392 A
6   -2.3548 0.0945  0.9933  -3.1174 A
7   -3.0944 -0.8559 0.6441  -2.8976 A
8   -0.4791 -0.8795 0.7027  -2.7338 A
9   -3.654  -6.27   0.265   -4.041  A
0   -3.1024 -1.871  0.1311  -5.7071 B
1   -0.1855 -0.8241 -0.2756 -6.6962 B
2   -3.2941 -2.0557 0.2471  -4.4969 B
3   -1.5004 -0.2482 0.9565  -0.6866 B
```

Comment: Duzhe dyakuyu) @MaxU or Thank you)

Comment: @IbrahimSefaOzyesil, yardımcı olduğuma sevindim (google translation) ;-)

Comment: neeet eta ne translator)), I speak Russian to save myself in Slavic countries and learned basic words on Ukranian in Ukrain. :) @MaxU

Comment: Privet ) I have one more question,
Each output in the row seems like this 

`"1.0164,""1.5813"",""0.9508"",""-3.4515""";TrainAP300 `. 

I want to write them each of them to different row seems like below ;

`1.0164    1.5813    0.9508    -3.4515    TrainAP300`

I also want to train my data in matlab api. In that case Matlab is getting angry my to my csv format )